# Python lists with both letters and integers

Tags: python

```
def main():
    list_one = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', '.', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0']
    list_two = ['4', 'R', '5', 'G', 'Z', '3', '2', 'D', 'A', 'E', 'X', 'Y', 'U', 'I', '6', 'W', '7', 'O', 'V', '8', 'F', 'Q', 'L', '0', 'J', '.', 'H', '9', 'C', 'B', 'N', 'S', 'P', 'M', '1', 'T', 'K']


    code = str(input("Enter message here. ")).upper()
    question = str(input("Would you like to encrypt or decrypt? ")).lower()


    if question == "encrypt":
       code_encrypt(list_one, list_two, code)
    #elif question == "decrypt":
    else:
        print("Invalid Input, Try Again")
        main()


def code_encrypt(x, y, z):
    message = ''
    for i in (z):
        for j in range(len(x)):
            if i == x[j]:
                message = message + repr(y[j])


    print(str.strip(message))



main()
```

output is 
Enter message here. yusef
Would you like to encrypt or decrypt? encrypt
'J''F''V''Z''3'

> > > problem is^^^ i cant have those '''' around the output. it needs to be JFVZ3

Comment: Welcome to SO, please review [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) as this question does not give us enough detail to answer your specific problem. Please include a [complete and verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example including the code producing the issue and expected/unexpected results

Comment: I think you came to python from some other language. I would recommend you learn some basics about python. for eg: you'd never have to write `for j in range(len(x))` and use `i == x[j]`

Answer (score 1):

Just remove "representation" conversion `repr()`:

```
def code_encrypt(x, y, z):
    message = ''
    for i in (z):
         for j in range(len(x)):
             if i == x[j]:
                message = message + y[j]
    print(message)
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185406/discussion-on-answer-by-mbo-python-lists-with-both-letters-and-integers).

Comment: @Yusef Saleh You can mark that answer solves your problem with green mark.